# "Топ-5 лучших" - плеоназм или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Вроде бы да, но, с другой стороны, теоретически возможен "топ-5 худших"?

Comment: В этом нет ничего плохого, какими словами ни называй. Буквально, это вершина списка лучших (первые 5 пунктов). "Лучших" одновременно представляют и несколькими более длинными списками. Поэтому трактовать это выражение нужно как "первые 5 из лучших".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Формально - Нет. Поскольку лучших может быть больше (или меньше) пяти, да и возможно нечто наподобие "вторая пятерка лучших" и проч. Плеоназмом (нежелательным)  было бы топ-5 **самых** лучших, поскольку "топ" и "самый" здесь значат одно и то же.

С другой стороны, о таких материях слушающий/читающий обычно не задумывается, поэтому "лучших" тут вполне можно и опустить, если на иное нет особых причин. 
"ТОП-5 вагоновожатых/рожениц/художественных_свистунов/" вполне самодостаточно. Просто из соображения экономии слов.

Другими словами, явной ошибки тут нет, но "лучших" вполне можно опустить, если без него все понятно.

(+)
"ТОП-5 худших" - нонсенс, имхо. Даже в "золотой малине" не применяется. Это "Боттом-5" по всем понятиям (которое тем более не используется).

Comment: Топ-5 лауреатов Шнобелевской премии — разве не топ-5 худших изобретателей?

Comment: *Топ-5 лауреатов Шнобелевской премии — разве не топ-5 худших изобретателей* - никогда не сталкивался с подобным. По мне так это совершенно противоестественное выражение. 1. Топ - это верх, вершина, а "худшие" всегда внизу. 2. Изобретатели не могут быть худшими. Это как "худший лауреат". Максимум - бесплодными, то есть никаких изобретений не сделавшие. 3. Там не изобретателей оценивают, а их изобретения - иногда на бесполезность, чаще - на недооцененность.. Я так это понимаю. Аналогично и с другими попытками употребить "топ худших".

Comment: Топ - вершина списка, а как список составлен - не нам знать. Топ-5 всемирных катостроф может быть?

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: Кто наживается на молодых мамочках Топ-10 сомнительных услуг ДНК-анализ пуповинной крови на генетические заболевания [Алеся Донская. Деньги на крови младенцев // «Русский репортер», 2013]

Comment: Итак, Топ-10 самых частых мужских ошибок при общении с женщинами. [Денис Шальнов. 10 ошибок соблазнения // «Психология на каждый день», 2010]

Comment: @М_Г  Про нацкорпус: Ну здесь-то даже нет слова "худший". И все одно - сильно смахивает оксюморон. Особенно во втором случае. В первом - не знаю без контекста, возможно просто словесная неуклюжесть.

Comment: *Топ - вершина списка, а как список составлен - не нам знать.* - в этом случае и само понятие "вершины" становится бессмысленным. Не может быть вершины у того, что не упорядочено по вертикали хотя бы в переносном смысле. *Топ-5 всемирных катастроф может быть?* - нет, мне не нравится. Но здесь даже нет слова "худший/лучший". ***"ТОП-5 лучших катастроф"*** - это что-то из параллельной реальности. Да хотя бы и "худших"...